# Error in accessing data from cursor in SQLite

Tags: android, debugging, cursor

I am working on a SQLite program and getting an error saying

```
2019-07-14 21:07:37.465 13538-13538/? E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 2 columns.
2019-07-14 21:07:37.466 13538-13538/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-07-14 21:07:37.467 13538-13538/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.xyz.sqlitelist, PID: 13538
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xyz.sqlitelist/com.example.xyz.sqlitelist.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

 Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
.
.

     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.xyz.sqlitelist/.MainActivity

```
String databaseToString(){
    StringBuilder dbString= new StringBuilder();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query=" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
            c.moveToNext();
            dbString.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")));
            dbString.append("\n");
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return dbString.toString();
}
```

Comment: It seems like there is no column `productname` in the table. If you added the column after you first run the app: uninstall the app, so the db is deleted and rerun.

Comment: I do have column in the table  \n \n
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            String query = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
                    ");";
            db.execSQL(query);

    }

Comment: What is the value of `COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME`?

Comment: private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME="_productname" ;

Comment: Now you see the problem?

Comment: Anyway, as I say in my answer don't hardcode the names. Use the variable's name. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column's name is "_productname" and not "productname" and this problem can be solved by not hardcoding this name since you have it in the variable `COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME`.
Also your code will miss rows because you use incorrectly `moveToFirst()`, `moveToNext()` and `isAfterLast()` when you only need `moveToNext()`:

```
String databaseToString() {
    StringBuilder dbString = new StringBuilder();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int index = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        dbString.append(c.getString(index)).append("\n");
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return dbString.toString();
}
```

Also that `WHERE 1` in the sql statement is not needed unless you want to change it later to something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code

```
String sql = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";
        Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);        
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
           if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) 
            {

             dbString.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")));

             dbString.append("\n");
            }
        }
c.close();
db.close();
return dbString.toString();
```